# How to pass data to Codeigniter Template

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter, partials

I'm using Phil Sturgeon's Template library (http://philsturgeon.co.uk) and I'm having trouble passing data to a partial.

I can set a title by doing `$this->template->title('some title')`

I'd like to set other attributes such as the meta description and the meta keywords, but I'm not sure how to pass it to the partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to build the template and pass to it all the data you need, for example:

```
$this->data->myTitle = "Your title";
$this->data->myKeyword = "key1, key2";
$this->template->build('your/view',$this->data);
```

then try to use it into your view with:

`$myTitle` and `$myKeyword`